# Proof of existence of an inverse formal power series

Tags: formal-power-series

We are given the formal power series 
$$
\alpha(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k*x^k
$$
and let us set deg($\alpha$) as the smallest $k = 0,1,2,..$ such that $a_0=a_1=...=a_{k-1}=0, a_k \not=0$.

I want to prove that $\alpha$ has an inverse in the set of formal power series with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if deg($\alpha$) is zero.

We can use the Lemma that deg($\alpha\beta$) = deg($\alpha$) + deg($\beta$). The direction '$\Leftarrow$' is already understood. Proving '$\Rightarrow$':
Let $\beta$ be the inverse of $\alpha$

$$deg(\alpha \beta) = deg(\alpha) + deg(\beta) = deg(1) = 0
$$
I don't know how to follow from this that $deg(\alpha) = 0$. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If two nonnegative integers add to $0$ what can they be?

Comment: Ah,zero, of course. I feel so stupid right now

Comment: Don't beat yourself up. Mathematicians do this all the time. You could delete the question if you like.

Comment: Thanks. It's ok. I think it is part of the learning process in general, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed it is. Often.